# Resolving merge conflicts in large csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, merge, perforce

.csproj file is in a xml format and it seems Visual Studio is adding there elements in random order. Perforce merge treats .csproj file as text file (order matters). This leads to a merging nightmare. Is there a way how to either:

1. (Preferred) Force perforce merge to treat .csproj file like xml file (order of nodes doesn't matter)
2. Force Visual Studio to keep some sort of ordering of xml elements inside .csproj (plugin perhaps?)

**UPDATE**

There seems to be feature request for it already - <strike>http://p4ideax.com/ideas/585/intelligent-support-for-xml-when-doing-merges</strike> though it doesn't have enough votes (yet).

**UPDATE 2** 
Seems perforce folks have moved their voting system, new url is
https://perforce.ideas.aha.io/ideas/P4D-I-77

Answer (score 5):

I just created a project on GitHub called [CsProjArrange](https://github.com/miratechcorp/CsProjArrange). I created it to fix the merging issues in my git repository. There are still some kinks which need to be ironed out, so I am open to some pull requests if you see anything that can be improved.

You just set it up as a clean filter in git for the .csproj files.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a known VS issue posted about supporting file patterns in project files. Are you referring to this issue? http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4512873-vs-ide-should-support-file-patterns-in-project-fil

Yes, in Perforce you can designate what type of file types you want per file using the typemap table, but I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. For example:

```
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Perforce-File-Type-Options
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_typemap.html
```

EXAMPLE

If you wanted your .csproj file to be treated like a Perforce binary file,
  you would add the following line to the typemap table:

```
  binary //....csproj
```

This will ensure on a go-forward basis your typemap table sets all
files on the server to binary.

For all current files, here is the command you need to run:

```
 p4 edit -t binary //....csproj
 p4 submit -d "Changing all of csproj to binary etc"
```

You can change a filetype with the 'edit', 'reopen' and 'add' commands:

-- p4 edit
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/edit.html#1040665

-- p4 reopen
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/reopen.html#1040665

-- p4 add
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/add.html#1040670